# hasOne relationship return error with mongodb (jenssegers) laravel

Tags: laravel, mongodb, eloquent, laravel-8

Error while API hit getting response:

```
{
   "message":"Declaration of Jenssegers//Mongodb//Relations//HasOne::getRelationQuery(Illuminate//Database//Eloquent//Builder $query, Illuminate//Database//Eloquent//Builder $parent, $columns = [...]) must be compatible with Illuminate//Database//Eloquent//Relations//HasOne::getRelationQuery()",
   "exception":"Symfony//Component//ErrorHandler//Error//FatalError",
   "file":"/var/www/html/jarvis/vendor/jenssegers/mongodb/src/Jenssegers/Mongodb/Relations/HasOne.php",
   "line":68,
   "trace":[
      
   ]
}
```

I am using ubuntu server and also i have deployed my code which was working fine on local, when i hit created API i am facing the error, also i have updated the path stated as
"use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\hasOne;" under User.php module with function

`public function seller(){ return $this->hasOne(Seller::class); }`

i want to use Seller id which is generated when New User is created, kindly help me out so i can achieve my goal, thanks in advance.

version details
Laravel Framework 8.83.23
Composer version 2.2.6
PHP 8.2.11
Mongod version v4.4.25

Comment: You might be having an issue with the `foreign_key` or `local_key`. I've had problems related to this... `return $this->hasOne(Phone::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');`